# How do I make a reusable component for the Cards and how can I use the new makeStyles of material-ui?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

In the `demo.js`, I wanted to use the `Card` along with its `CardHeader` and put wordings inside the `CardContent`. Also, I will be using the `CardComponent` in other files as well. How can I make the `CardComponent` reusable?

Sample codes: https://codesandbox.io/s/basiccard-material-demo-forked-kkshx?file=/demo.js

Below are the codes for the `demo.js`:

```
import * as React from "react";

import CardComponent from "./CardComponent";

export default function BasicCard() {
  return (
    <>
      <h1>Hello</h1>
      <CardComponent />
    </>
  );
}
```

Below are the codes for the `CardComponent`:

```
import React from "react";

import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { CardHeader } from "@mui/material";

const CardComponent = () => {
  const CardStyle = {
    maxWidth: 500,
    margin: "0 auto",
    marginBottom: "1rem",
    marginTop: "1rem"
  };
  return (
    <Card sx={{ minWidth: 275 }} elevation={5} style={CardStyle}>
      <CardHeader title="Card Header Title here" />
      <CardContent>//content here</CardContent>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```

I have another question as well under this component. Coming from material-ui4, mui5 was kind of confusing as I can no longer use the `makeStyles`. I tried adding this in the codesandbx example, however, it will say that dependency not found:

```
import { makeStyles } from '@mui/styles';
```

Hence, I settled with const `CardStyle`. Any help on how can I implement the newer version of the `makeStyles`? Also, do I need to install other dependecies from material-ui to make it work? Below is the `package.json file`.

[image]

Also in: https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/sgqhh3/how_do_i_make_a_reusable_component_for_the_cards/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make it reusable adding props to your child card component. You can add as many props you want to make different cards using the same pattern.

To give styles to the component in mui v5 you have to use styled. You have to import it from @mui/material/styles

Here is the whole code of the new card component

```
import React from "react";
import {styled} from "@mui/material/styles"
import Card from "@mui/material/Card";
import CardContent from "@mui/material/CardContent";
import { CardHeader } from "@mui/material";

const StyledCard = styled((props) => (
  <Card
      {...props}
  />
))(({ theme }) => ({
  maxWidth: 500,
    margin: "0 auto",
    marginBottom: "1rem",
    marginTop: "1rem"
}));


const CardComponent = (props) => {
  const {title,content}=props

  return (
    <StyledCard sx={{ minWidth: 275 }} elevation={5}>
      <CardHeader title={title} />
      <CardContent>{content}</CardContent>
    </StyledCard>
  );
};

export default CardComponent;
```

And here it is the whole codesandbox.

[image: Edit BasicCard Material Demo (forked)]

Comment: Thank you. Just one last question though, How can I specify the font size for the title and content?

Comment: @RavenousRed you can use strings on the title but you can also use elements on title and content so you can add a <Typography> element of material ui and change it fontsize. 

You can also change the sizes on the styledCard. It depends of what do you want for your component.